# Silverlight 4 DataBinding: Binding to ObservableCollection<string> not working anymore

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Upgrading from SL3 -> SL4. First problem: this throws a parser exception:

```
<StackPanel Name={Binding} /> (same with x:Name)
```

Collection is `ObservableCollection<string>`. Worked fine in SL3. So it seems that SL4 doen't allow binding to the Name property. Huh?

So: changed to

```
<StackPanel Tag={Binding} />
```

... since I just need to ID the control in code behind. So here's the bug ('cuz this has got to be a bug!):

In this frag, AllAvailableItems is an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
<ItemsControl Name="lbItems"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AllAvailableItems}"
                  Height="Auto"
                  Width="Auto"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="12,6,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}"
                              Checked="ItemChecked_Click"
                              Unchecked="ItemUnchecked_Click"
                              Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"
                              Grid.Row="0">
                        <CheckBox.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource FormLJustStyle}" />
                        </CheckBox.Content>
                    </CheckBox>

                    <StackPanel Tag="{Binding}"
                                Orientation="Vertical"
                                Grid.Row="1">
                        <configControls:ucLanguage /> <!-- simple user control -->
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

In the code behind, I use a recursive function to find the Dependency object with either the Name or Tag property provided:

```
public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name, DependencyProperty propToUse) where T : DependencyObject
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
      {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        string controlName = child.GetValue(propToUse) as string;
        if (controlName == name)
        {
          return child as T;
        }
        else
        {
          T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name, propToUse);
          if (result != null)
            return result;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

OK, get this: in the code behind, I can get the control that is ORDERED FIRST in the XAML! In other words, if I put the CheckBox first, I can retrieve the CheckBox, but no StackPanel. And vice-versa. This all worked fine in SL3.

Any help, ideas ... ?

Thanks - Kurt

Comment: Is AllAvailableItems your DataContext? You mentioned it but I don't see it referenced in your code. I tested your situation with hardcoded 'Tag's and I could successfully retrieve the StackPanel so it must be a problem with your binding.

Comment: Like I said, this code works great with SL3. The AllAvailableItems property is a member of my ViewModel and is available at runtime - as I mentioned, I can use it's values to instantiate EITHER a Checkbox bound in my ItemsControl, OR a StackPanel - but not both, and only the one that is declared first in the Xaml!

Comment: You haven't defined what consitutes "this worked in SL3", in what does it work? You describe the fact that only the item ordered first is return by the function, what else were you expecting? It seems to me that the function will search for the required item that matches the criteria you ar looking for and return that. Stands to reason that it will return the first one it will come across but you seem to indicate that this is a problem, how so?

Comment: There are 2 problems here: 1) SL4 won't allow data binding to the Name or x:Name properties of controls. Bummer, but oh well.

More crucially, 2) Binding isn't working correctly here, IMO. I can bind a collection to an ItemsControl, yes? And I can assign item properties (individual strings) to the Tag properties of controls within the DataTemplate, yes? As many as I want!

BUT ... I can only use this Tag property to retrieve the FIRST DECLARED control in the template using the VisualTreeHelper? Try it yourself - smells like a bug to me. Hope I'm wrong, I've written a hack but it ain't pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug.

Your loop will never go past the first object because you return the child upon first match.

Add it to a collection and return a collection instead.

Something like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildrenByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name, DependencyProperty propToUse) where T : DependencyObject
{
  List<T> children = new List<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
  {
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
    string controlName = child.GetValue(propToUse) as string;
    if (controlName == name)
    {
      children.add(child as T);
    }
   // ...
  }
  return children;
}
```

**EDIT:**
This of course is granted that you don't call your code multiple times using the return child element. In that case, you should provide the calling method code, so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I found this myself earlier today - because SL4 doesn't let you bind to Name or x:Name, I switched to Tag, and in doing so introduced this bug. I fixed it by checking the type like so:

if (controlName == name && child.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)))
{
  return child as T;
}

The cast was failing - since there were 2 controls with the same Tag property! Easy fix, shoulda caught it sooner. Sometimes when you are upgrading to a new major version there's an inclination to imagine bugs, eh? Thank the good dude!